# Angular Infinite Digest Loop with promise.then()

Tags: angularjs, promise

**The problem:** Using a `this.promise.then(function(){})` function inside a controller method seems to create a $rootScope:infDig loop although the returned value of that method does not change. It's worth noting that the infinite digest loop is gone when removing the .then() line (see code).

**The code:**
`{{ getSelectedProjects() }}` in the view and the following method in the attached controller

```
var vm = this;
vm.getSelectedProjects = function() {
  if (angular.isUndefined(vm.hello)) {
    vm.hello = "hello"
    vm.promise = $q.when("hello i am a resolved promise")
  }
  vm.promise //In my original code, this promise is returned by a service (MyService.getPromise()). The resolved value of the returned promise may change which is why the service needs to be called at each digest cycle.
  .then(function (ans) {
    vm.hello = ans;
  }); //remove .then(...) function and there is no infinite digest loop anymore
  return vm.hello;
}
```

**The question:** Why is this creating an infinite digest loop although the returned value does not change ? How can I avoid it (I badly need the result of that promise)?.

**My shaky thoughts:** I guess it has to do with the fact .then() each time returns a *new* promise. The documentation does not state it, but if that promise is each time attached to the controller object (vm), this might be considered as a state change of the controller and trigger a new digest loop, which re-evaluates vm.getSelectedProjects() and again attaches a new promise to the controller, etc.

**EDIT**
My hypothesis in "shaky thoughts" does not seem fully correct or complete, as the problem persists with this code:

```
vm.getSelectedProjects = function() {
  if (angular.isUndefined(vm.hello)) {
    vm.hello = "hello"
  }
  $q.when("hello i am a resolved promise")//this object is not attached to the controller object
  .then(function () {});
  return vm.hello;
}
```

Comment: Is that the error you see in the console by any chance https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig ?

Comment: Exactly, adding it to the post.

Comment: Ok, so you know how many time you're calling that function when you bind it to the view? On every digest cycle, which happens a lot! You can use one time binding, or explain why you're binding a function to the view like that. You should bind the scope properties, but not a function (Unless you're binding it to an event handler)

Comment: And the loop is created by the use of a promise, when it resolved - a new digest cycle starts and this function gets called again and again

Comment: "$q is integrated with the $rootScope.Scope Scope model observation mechanism in AngularJS," resolution triggers new digest loop

Comment: I simplified the code a lot to isolate the issue. In reality, vm.promise is a promise returned by a service that resolves in an array that will be used in the view. In other words, when the promise resolves, vm.hello is set to its resolved value. The resolved value of that promise can change, which is why I need to call my function on every digest cycle, and update vm.hello only if the returned value has changed. Is this not a clean implementation? What would you suggest?

Comment: I edited the original code so that it better reflects my problem and what I want to achieve.

Comment: An angular expression like this should not have side effects. Especially not the one of registering a new promise callback, that will be called at the end of the digest, which will cause the expression to be reevaluated, which will register a new promise callback, that will be called at the end of the digest, which will cause the expression to be reevaluated etc. etc.

Comment: I agree @JBNizet, however the promise returned by my service is generally (but not always) the same object, so that should not trigger an infitite digest loop. I understand now that the resolution of the new promise created by .then() *does* trigger a new digest cycle, and so an infinite loop. However, I still do not understand how to print the resolution of a promise *that might change* in my view.

Comment: It's not the promise. It's the callback. Every time your function is executed, it passes a new callback to then(), and this callback is executedat the end of the digest loop, and triggers a new one, which reevaluates the method, etc. Just don't call a service and register a callback to a promise from inside that method. That should be done from an event handler (click, whatever), or from your controller constructor. Not from an expression evaluation.

Comment: @JBNizet Care to provide an example? Having exact the same issue here and bumping my head against the wall for a few hours, still have no clue about how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the problems encountered and the comments we created coding guidelines for working with promises in our project. Found it interesting to share it as I haven't seen this documented anywhere.

## Coding guideline: Working with promises

### Use of promises

Promises are amazing objects, however a wrong use can create headaches. Therefore we have a few guidelines :

- Do not use promises in views
- Do not use promises in controllers, except in functions called by event handlers (click, init, etc.), the controller construction function (=executed only once) or in animations
- If a promise result is used in a view, the model (or the manager) should contain a property that is empty by default and set to the resolved value when the promise is resolved. The controller just returns that value.

### Implementation

This is the kind of structure that should be in the model, manager, or other service, as close as possible to the data source. NOT in controllers :

```
  var myApiMethod = function() {
    //We call "caching" the fact that this method is executed only if $scope.item is undefined.
    If (angular.isUndefined($scope.item) { 
      $scope.item = {}
      $http(xxx).then(function(value){
        $scope.item = value;
      });
      return $scope.item
    }
  }
```

The controller then just returns the answer of myApiMethod. You might need to check if 'myService.myApiMethod() != {}'.

In the service we can define a caching behaviour (ex: retrieve data from backend every 2 hours, at a certain event clear the cache, etc. ). As long as there is only one single source of truth (coming from the service in this case, not from the controller) concerning the object to be returned you can easilly play around with this.

### Argumentation

*Why not to use promises in views or in controller methods called by expression evaluations (e.g., {{ vm.getMyApiMethodResult() }} *:

- Including promises in views is a feature that has been desactivated in Angular 1.x
- If myApiMethod is put in the controller without the caching and then used in an expression evaluation (e.g., {{ myCtrl.getMyApiMethod() }} ), it will create an infinite digest cycle, because the resolution of the promise will trigger a new digest cycle, that will again call the vm.getMyApiMethod() function, etc. (more info in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928818/angular-infinite-digest-loop-with-promise-then) )
- Why not put myApiMethod in t he controller with the caching (like implementation above) to make sure myApiMethod is called only once and avoid the infinite digest loop? Three reasons:

  1. if the response of myApiMethod() changes into a new object, $scope.item will not be updated.
  2. Another drawback of this (that we used a lot in the past, you might still see wrong implementations in the code) is that it creates a lot of duplicate code as we need to duplicate this quite heavy code structure (that can become much more complex when several promises are involved) in all controllers calling myApiMethod()
  3. If you "cache" in the controller, you might end up with different controllers returning different answers although they both return the answer from the same service 'myApiMethod' but at different moments in time.

**Remember :** This guideline only applies to controller functions called in expression evaluations. You might need promises in controller functions called by event handlers (click, etc.) and that's fine because these functions are not called at each of angular's digest cycles.